# Kafka Configuration Change

Tags: apache-kafka

I am trying to tweak two config params of a kafka topic dynamically (without restart) i.e. **flush.messages,flush.ms** to restrict the no. of writes to disk, as disk seems to be bottleneck in our case. But these configuration changes are not getting applied to the topic. flush.ms has been set to 10000ms but it writes to disk at every 5000ms. Any idea why this config param isn't being picked up by the topic.

Kafka version used - 0.8.1.1

command(s) used -

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper zkHost:zkPort  --topic topicName --alter --config flush.messages=200000
bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper zkHost:zkPort  --topic topicName --alter --config flush.ms=20000
```

How to change the log flush interval if this doesn't works?

Comment: How you confirmed the config updations doesn't applied to the topics?

Comment: If i do a describe for the topic name `topicName`, it appears in the configs. But i ran a small shell command to track the last modified, last updated properties of the kafka log file, and  it was getting changed every 5000ms. @KamalC